# what random function the ffmpeg filter expression called?

Tags: ffmpeg

for example this `random(-1)` in geq:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc=s=10x10:r=25:d=4 -vf geq=lum='255':cb='255*random(-1)':cr='255*random(-1)',scale=200:200:flags=neighbor -bf 0 test.mp4
```

I always get exactly the same color of first 2 pixels in the first frame.  And the first frame always has very similar colors. Star from 3rd frame its start to getting better. Moreover, the random() seems only introduce random inside single frame. The sequence of first pixel of each frame is exactly the same:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc=s=1x1:r=25:d=4 -vf geq=lum=255:cb='255*random(-1)':cr='255*random(-1)',scale=10:10:flags=neighbor -vframes 10 f%05d.png
```

[image: 1st run]

[image: 2nd run]

I looked into [source code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/5c0d1f78968ce088b6750a0bfdc2a9c1ddc3692d/libavutil/eval.c#L232), but I cannot see what random function actually get called:

```
        case e_random:{
            int idx= av_clip(eval_expr(p, e->param[0]), 0, VARS-1);
            uint64_t r= isnan(p->var[idx]) ? 0 : p->var[idx];
            r= r*1664525+1013904223;
            p->var[idx]= r;
            return e->value * (r * (1.0/UINT64_MAX));
        }
```

How do I suppose to get proper randomness in the geq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with multiplier 1664525 and increment 1013904223.

You can of course modify it to suit your needs. Check out `av_get_random_seed` for more sources of randomness.

Comment: so I guess from command line there is no way to use other random generator.